# Is there a way to use Google's Javascript client login without a pop up?

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-client-login

I'm using Google's client login in my client-side javascript, which causes a popup to appear for auth and google login. However, I'd love to configure the sign-in to redirect to the popup's url, auth the user, then come back to my site instead.

I can't find anything in the documentation about configuring pop up vs redirect: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference but I wanted to see if anyone else had success configuring the client-side login for this.

The alternative is using backend auth which I know allows redirects.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#redirecting can help.   Demo :  https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript library requires a window to pop up. If you want to implement it by redirecting users to auth, it will be a server side implementation like @osmanraifgunes pointed out in the comment.