# Change page URL instead of pop up with Google Sign In Button

Tags: google-signin

In response to possible duplicate: This question pertains to a specific button Google generates using a `<script>` tag targeting a particular `<div>`, so is different than the question linked below.

I want to, if possible, use the automatically generated Google sign-in button, reference here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#add_a_google_sign-in_button

However, this button, by default, launches the sign-in as a popup, which I can't use due to a platform limitation on the app my application is being embedded into.

Is there a way to make this window open by changing the document.URL rather than as a popup? I know there are other ways to accomplish Google sign-in, but I'm trying to be a good(lazy) programmer and do it the simplest way first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use Google's Javascript client login without a pop up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648165/is-there-a-way-to-use-googles-javascript-client-login-without-a-pop-up)